# How to print the recursive stack in Python

Tags: python, recursion

How do I print or show the recursive stack in Python when I'm running a recursive function?

Comment: What stack do you mean? could you explain you question a bit more?

Comment: Every time a recursive function is called, the language builds a stack of the result... Does this make sense?

Comment: @AAA I've updated my answer below, please see if there's anything else you have in mind that you can't access through frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what you want but as far as I get your question, you can print the stack of function callers in a recursive manner like the following, using the python [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html).

```
import inspect, sys

max_recursion_depth = 10

def rec_func(recursion_index):
    if recursion_index == 0:
        return

    rec_func(recursion_index-1)

    current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
    calframe = inspect.getouterframes(current_frame, 2)

    frame_object = calframe[0][0]

    print("Recursion-%d: %s" % (max_recursion_depth - recursion_index, frame_object.f_locals))
    print("Passed parameters: %s" % (sys._getframe(1).f_locals) )


rec_func(max_recursion_depth)
```

You can also use `sys.get_frame()` to access the current frame and by using the `f_locals` property, you can access the parameters passed to the current frame, in a recursive manner, you can observe this parameter decreasing.

Mostly all Information you want about the stack is also accessible from the *frame* objects that you can get as I've brought above.